# SparkSession cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark, as I typed the program, got an error saying `SparkSession cannot be resolved to a type`.

When I opened the .jar file and saw, the SparkSession.class was not present in the file. What to do?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include sample code to help you better.

Comment: Is this in a spark-submit command or is it in spark-shell?